# <textarea> inside <foreignObject> handles as expected in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, svg, textarea

I'm creating a textarea inside a foreignObject in an SVG as follows:

```
var doc = document.getElementById("cover");
var foreign = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"foreignObject");
var textarea = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml","textarea");

foreign.setAttributeNS(null,"x",40);
foreign.setAttributeNS(null,"y",40);
foreign.setAttributeNS(null,"width",500);
foreign.setAttributeNS(null,"height",200);
doc.appendChild(foreign);

textarea.setAttributeNS(null,"xmlns","http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/");
textarea.textContent = "Text goes here.";
foreign.appendChild(textarea);
```

This works fine in Chrome. However, in Firefox, I can't see the textarea at all. When I check with Firebug, it does exist, but firefox has forced static positioning on it, and depending on how I scroll, the highlighted box from hovering over the object in the html tab isn't necessarily even inside the svg. Even when it is, I can't see the textarea. What can I do to fix this in Firefox? For reference, I'm using the newest versions of both browsers (updated a few hours ago).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/BYusk/) if I change this line:

```
textarea.setAttributeNS(null,"xmlns","http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/");
```

To this:

```
textarea.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/","xmlns","http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/");
```

I think Firefox is just being more strict about the namespaces.  It could be a bug, but [this indicates it's accepted](http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/) to require the `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/` for DOM processing:

> The prefix `xmlns:` was specified as a syntactic device for declaring
>   namespaces, but was not itself associated with any namespace name by
>   the Jan 1999 namespaces specfication. But in some processing contexts,
>   e.g. [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM), it is useful to represent all XML attributes as (namespace
>   name, local name) pairs. For this purpose, the namespace name
>   `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/` is assigned.

Comment: That works for firefox. Any idea how to make it work for IE, or is that a whole other can of worms?

Comment: @Fibericon IE only started supporting SVG in version 9 and support is [well behind the other major browsers](http://www.codedread.com/svg-support.php).  For older versions you could try [svgweb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/) but I think that native support is the only real option if you're going to use `foreignObject`.